# What is a background check?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, translation, simile

I wanna understand the meaning of the background check? Like I don’t know how to do one or even get one. I really want to know the purpose of a background check.

Comment: You can Google the term to understand what employers are looking for. They usually don't do the looking themselves, but farm it out to specialized services.

Comment: I googled for you.  Try this: https://techjury.net/blog/what-does-a-background-check-consist-of/

Answer (score 1):

Boykah ... the purpose of the BACKGROUND CHECK, is for employers or other 'entities' to obtain an unbiased report on WHOM they are dealing with, in the person who is being 'checked out'.  The Background Check will include such things as Criminal Record, Credit Report, Education, Employment, and more.

Wikipedia explains it overall quite well:  *The objective of background checks is to ensure the safety and security of the employees in the organization. These checks are often used by employers as a means of judging a job candidate's past mistakes, character, and fitness, and to identify potential hiring risks for safety and security reasons.*

In decades past a person's reputation was a treasured element of their life and livelihood.  Today, because more people are lax in the care of their reputation; as well as a growing concept that one's reputation is more 'flexible'; employers and others dealing with an individual find it necessary to do their 'due diligence' (you may be interested in the background on this term as well) and make sure the individual will be a POSITIVE addition to their entity and NOT a negative problem to be avoided.

This leads to all sorts of complications, oversights, prejudices and negative social outflow, but it's become the 'lesser of two evils'.  Choose bad by being lax in the 'background check', or be seen as a bit more antiseptic and less personal, and NOT inherit an unwanted problem.

Comment: Your analysis is a well-written opinion. An authoritative answer here does not include my opinion, though, or *I hope*. And frankly, with the work done once you pointed to Wikipedia, the question itself needs no work on our part.

Comment: A referenced and well discussed view. I have removed the unnecessary epilogue.